# Behavior of qualified name using private inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

When compiling the following example in msvc, I get

> 'Interface' not accessible because 'Base' uses 'private' to
>   inherit from 'Interface'

in the line marked with `Error`. When the call to `foo` is qualified with a type alias of the same type, it works. I tested with msvc and ideone.

Why are the two calls not equal?

```
struct Interface {};

template<class T>
struct Base : private T
{
    void foo() {}
};

using BaseX =   Base<Interface>;

class Derived : Base<Interface>
{
    Derived() {
        Base<Interface>::foo();   // Error
        BaseX::foo();             // Works
    }
};
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/cTQmYP)

Comment: Looks like a msvc bug

Comment: @DieterLücking, I tried it using g++ 4.9.3 and `BaseX::foo();` works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Injected-class-names.

The name `Interface` is injected into the scope of the class `Interface` as if it's a public member, and in turn inherited by `Base<Interface>` (as a private member, since you are using private inheritance).

When you write `Base<Interface>::foo()` in `Derived`, unqualified name lookup for `Interface` looks first at `Derived` and its base class, finds `Interface` in the base class, and then access control kicks in because that name is `private`.

The simplest fix is to just write `Base::foo()`, or even just `foo()` if it isn't virtual and you aren't planning to write a `foo()` in `Derived`.

If you have to include the template argument for some reason, then write `Base<::Interface>`.

Comment: Why are we looking up `Interface` though?

Comment: @Barry Um, you wrote `Base<Interface>::foo();`...not sure why you think it won't be looked up.

Comment: @Barry Well, before we lookup `foo`, we need to know what scope to look it up in (or, what `Base<Interface>` is)...so you lookup `Base` and `Interface`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I inherit from several `Base<X>` and need `Base<X>::` to disambiguate. What is the most elegant solution for this case?

Comment: @BetaCarotin Qualify the name.

Comment: @DieterLücking So it seems. 4.9+ rejects it.

Comment: I consider it a bug (for every compiler doing that)

Comment: @BetaCarotin I'd suggest `Base<::X>` instead of `Base<X>`. This will look up `X` in the global scope, instead of the local one. So you don't need typedefs / usings.

Comment: @DieterLücking what a bug? Rejecting the code? That's what the standard says they should do.

Comment: @T.C. "Downvoter care to comment?" do not ask that, just  accept it (I have no vote here)